Ampscript set variable not working
Given that I have already declared my variables... I am trying to set some values to those variables, based on whether a row of data already exists or not...
 VAR @brandID, @Content, @Header, @subscriberkey, @cottage1ID, @cottage2ID, @cottage1Name, @cottage2Name, @viewDate1, @viewedProperties, @viewedPropertyRow, @viewedPropertiesRows, @viewPropertyCount, @viewDate2, @currentDate, @dayDiff,  @bookingRows, @AllBookingRow1, @bookingRowCount, @AllBookingRowCount1, @viewedPropertyID, @AllBookingRow2, @AllBookingRowCount2, @viewedOtherPropertiesRows, @viewedOtherPropertyRow, @viewedOtherProperties, @viewOtherPropertyCount

Could someone explain to me, why this works:
 SET @viewedPropertiesRows = LookupRows("Viewed Properties","Subscriber Key", @subscriberkey, "brandID", @brandID)
 SET @viewPropertyCount = rowcount(@viewedPropertiesRows)
   IF @viewPropertyCount > 0 THEN
    SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedPropertiesRows, 1)
    SET @cottage1Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1Name")
    SET @cottage2Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2Name")
    SET @cottage1ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1PropertyID")
    SET @cottage2ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2PropertyID")
    SET @viewDate1 = FormatDate(field(@viewedPropertyRow,"View1_happenedAt"), 'yyyy-MM-DD')
    SET @dayDiff = DateDiff(@viewDate1,@currentDate,"D")
   ENDIF
  
 IF(EMPTY(@viewPropertyCount) OR @viewPropertyCount == 0) THEN

    SET @viewedOtherPropertiesRows = LookupRows("Viewed Properties","Subscriber Key", @subscriberkey, "brandID", 1)
    SET @viewOtherPropertyCount = rowcount(@viewedOtherPropertiesRows)
    IF @viewOtherPropertyCount > 0 THEN
        SET @viewedOtherPropertyRow = row(@viewedOtherPropertiesRows, 1)
        SET @cottage1NameOther = field(@viewedOtherPropertyRow,"cottage1Name")
        SET @cottage2NameOther = field(@viewedOtherPropertyRow,"cottage2Name")
        SET @cottage1IDOther =  field(@viewedOtherPropertyRow,"cottage1PropertyID")
        SET @cottage2IDOther =  field(@viewedOtherPropertyRow,"cottage2PropertyID")
        SET @viewDate1Other = FormatDate(field(@viewedOtherPropertyRow,"View1_happenedAt"), 'yyyy-MM-DD')
        SET @dayDiffOther = DateDiff(@viewDate1Other,@currentDate,"D")
    ENDIF

  ENDIF

but this doesn't:
    SET @viewedPropertiesRows = LookupRows("Viewed Properties","Subscriber Key", @subscriberkey, "brandID", @brandID)
    SET @viewPropertyCount = rowcount(@viewedPropertiesRows)
    IF @viewPropertyCount > 0 THEN
        SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedPropertiesRows, 1)
        SET @cottage1Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1Name")
        SET @cottage2Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2Name")
        SET @cottage1ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1PropertyID")
        SET @cottage2ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2PropertyID")
        SET @viewDate1 = FormatDate(field(@viewedPropertyRow,"View1_happenedAt"), 'yyyy-MM-DD')
        SET @dayDiff = DateDiff(@viewDate1,@currentDate,"D")

    ELSEIF(EMPTY(@viewPropertyCount) OR @viewPropertyCount == 0) THEN

        SET @viewedOtherPropertiesRows = LookupRows("Viewed Properties","Subscriber Key", @subscriberkey, "brandID", 1)
        SET @viewPropertyCount = rowcount(@viewedPropertiesRows)
        IF @viewPropertyCount > 0 THEN
            SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedPropertiesRows, 1)
            SET @cottage1Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1Name")
            SET @cottage2Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2Name")
            SET @cottage1ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1PropertyID")
            SET @cottage2ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2PropertyID")
            SET @viewDate1 = FormatDate(field(@viewedPropertyRow,"View1_happenedAt"), 'yyyy-MM-DD')
            SET @dayDiff = DateDiff(@viewDate1,@currentDate,"D")
        ENDIF
        
    ENDIF

I feel like I am going crazy, but there must be a rational reason! many thanks

You're mixing your other variables.
In the second example, in the ELSEIF section,
the SET @viewPropertyCount = rowcount(@viewedPropertiesRows)
should be: SET @viewPropertyCount = rowcount(@viewedOtherPropertiesRows)
and the: SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedPropertiesRows, 1)
should be: SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedOtherPropertiesRows, 1)
I'd probably write it something like this:
%%[

set @debug = 1

SET @viewedPropertiesRows = LookupRows("Viewed Properties","Subscriber Key", @subscriberkey, "brandID", @brandID)
SET @viewPropertyCount1 = rowcount(@viewedPropertiesRows)

IF @viewPropertyCount1 > 0 THEN

    SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedPropertiesRows, 1)
    SET @cottage1Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1Name")
    SET @cottage2Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2Name")
    SET @cottage1ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1PropertyID")
    SET @cottage2ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2PropertyID")
    SET @viewDate1 = FormatDate(field(@viewedPropertyRow,"View1_happenedAt"), 'yyyy-MM-DD')
    SET @dayDiff = DateDiff(@viewDate1,@currentDate,"D")

ELSE

    set @brand = 1
    SET @viewedPropertiesRows = LookupRows("Viewed Properties","Subscriber Key", @subscriberkey, "brandID", @brand)
    SET @viewPropertyCount2 = rowcount(@viewedPropertiesRows)

    IF @viewPropertyCount2 > 0 THEN

        SET @viewedPropertyRow = row(@viewedPropertiesRows, 1)
        SET @cottage1Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1Name")
        SET @cottage2Name = field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2Name")
        SET @cottage1ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage1PropertyID")
        SET @cottage2ID =  field(@viewedPropertyRow,"cottage2PropertyID")
        SET @viewDate1 = FormatDate(field(@viewedPropertyRow,"View1_happenedAt"), 'yyyy-MM-DD')
        SET @dayDiff = DateDiff(@viewDate1,@currentDate,"D")

    ELSE

        raiseError("no properties found", 1)

    ENDIF


ENDIF

if @debug == 1 then

    output(concat("<br>brandID: ", @brandID))
    output(concat("<br>viewPropertyCount1: ", @viewPropertyCount1))
    output(concat("<br>viewPropertyCount2: ", @viewPropertyCount2))
    output(concat("<br>cottage1Name: ", @cottage1Name))
    output(concat("<br>cottage2Name: ", @cottage2Name))
    output(concat("<br>cottage1ID: ", @cottage1ID))
    output(concat("<br>cottage2ID: ", @cottage2ID))
    output(concat("<br>viewDate1: ", @viewDate1))
    output(concat("<br>dayDiff: ", @dayDiff))
    output(concat("<br>currentDate: ", @currentDate))

endif 

]%%


Ah yes you're right - good spot, thanks Adam. I've re-written it 5 or 6 times and can't think that I missed that each time but your solution seems nicer, will give it a go and report back!

v strange, some variables output, but for some reason cottage1Name is still null, despite having  a value in the lookup DE, there's no char limit or anything is there? (field length is set to 100 chars)

No character limits, no.  But perhaps leading or trailing spaces in the DE field name.

Updated my example above to include a method you might try for debugging.  Just toggle the @debug variable to 0 when you're satisfied with how it's functioning.

can't thank you enough for your help Adam.... The debugging really helped... turns out the contentBlock I was pulling in was overwriting the values, logging them out helped me find a solution!
